# Using the actual subscript as a variable within thecontext of definitions using the Notation package and Symbolize

Tags: formatting

I've gotten into the habit of using subscripted variables, invoking the `Notation` package and `Symbolize`. Now, I'd like to be able to write something like

```
In[1]:= Sum[a<sub>i<sub> ,{i,1,2}]
Out[1]:= a<sub>1<sub> + a<sub>2<sub>
```

but get

```
Out[1]:= 2 a<sub>i<sub>
```

I've tried `RemoveSymbolize[myBoxes]` to get rid of definitions, but it has no effect. I know that

```
In[2]:= Sum[Subscript[a,i],{i,1,2}]
```

works as I'd like and may have to do, but I'm curious if the subscripted variables entered using `Ctrl`+`_` can be made to work.

Comment: When you use `Symbolize` the the complete variable plus subscript is treated as a single symbol -- which is the purpose of the function. To see this wrap `Head` around your symbolized variable and then try `AtomQ`. Then try that again with a "normal" subscripted variable. So the "i" that is subscripted is not available for iterations when you use `Symbolize` ...by design. To remove symbols evaluate `ClearNotations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating as per the image (using a pasted image because symbolize does not paste well) will help clear things up:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to get back to this before now, but I appreciate your quick and clear response.  I have the correct "picture" in my head now for how Symbolize works. Now I need to play around and see why the examples for using markup formats in the Exchange (html, LaTeX, etc.) didn't work for me.