# Generating Suffixes

Tags: functions

I am doing a large Matrix calculation in which I need to generate symbols first like

$F^{\mu\nu}$ I would like to get $\mu\nu = 00, 11, 22, 33$ and so on.

I need to have the symbols before I can assign anything. Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: something like this: `Table[Superscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalF], 
  Row[{\[Mu], \[Nu]}]], {\[Mu], 0, 3}, {\[Nu], 0, 3}]`? But whether this is appropriate for later calculations is uncertain unless you provide details. You may need to use `Symbolize`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:`Symbolize`?

Comment: You may be better off defining an array, for example, a 5 by 3 array `capF = Array[f, {5, 3}]`

Comment: @rasher `Symbolize` turns things into symbols, i.e. `Head[thing]` is `Symbol` and `AtomQ[thing]` is `True`. e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38622/using-the-actual-subscript-as-a-variable-within-thecontext-of-definitions-using/38629#38629

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:Ah, part of `Notation` package. Cheers!

Comment: Cool :) @MikeHoneychurch