# What's the difference between variables with and without a subscript?

Tags: symbols, syntax-highlighting

If I input $x = a + b$, the $x$, $a$ and $b$ are blue. When I hit <kbd>Shif</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the $x$ turns black, indicating the kernel now knows this variable. But when I input $x_r = a + b$, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, $x_r$ is still blue.

What's the difference between variables with and without subscript?

Comment: Try wrapping `AtomQ` and `Head` around your variables to see the difference. This might be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38622/using-the-actual-subscript-as-a-variable-within-thecontext-of-definitions-using/38629#38629

Comment: $x_r$ is `Subscript[x]`, so your definition is actually more about defining `Subscript` than about `x`.

Comment: Evaluate `?? Subscript` to see what _Mathematica_ has done with your definition. It may also suggest to you why subscripted variables are fine for text formatting, but not so good for computation.

Answer (score 5):

On the simplest level, the difference is that `x` is a symbol, which is an atomic object to a *Mathematica* kernel, while subscripting `x` makes it an non-atomic expression, in this case an object with head `Subscript`.

```
 Clear[x]
 {Head[x], AtomQ[x]}
```

> ```
>  {Symbol, True}
> ```

The `FullForm` of a subscripted variable with subscript `i` is

```
Subscript[x, i]
```

Its head is clearly `Subscript` and it's not an atom.

```
 Clear[x, i]; AtomQ[Subscript[x, i]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

On a deeper level, there is a difference in how assignments to symbols and subscripted objects are handled. In both cases, an expression of the form

```
{HoldPattern[...] :> a + b}
```

is recorded by the kernel. However, they are stored in different kinds of internal lists. An assignment to a symbol is stored as an own-value of the symbol; All assignments to subscripted variables are stored as down-values of `Subscript`.

```
Clear[x]; x = a + b; OwnValues @ x
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x] :> a + b}
> ```

```
Clear[Subscript, x, i]; Subscript[x, i] = a + b; DownValues @ Subscript
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[Subscript[x, i]] :> a + b}
> ```

If you were use many subscripted variables in a *Mathematica* session, you would build up a big list of rules in the down-values of `Subscript`, slowing down references to subscripted variables. But this is probably not the worst problem encountered with `Subscript`. Consider doing a long computation with subscripted variables. Somewhere in the notebook, you evaluate

```
Subscript[x, i] = a + b;
```

Now, much later later and in a distant cell, you want to take a symbolic derivative. Like so:

```
Clear[x, i]; D[Subscript[x, i][t], {t, 2}]
```

> ```
> Derivative[2][a + b][t]
> ```

Not what you expected? It is so easy to forget that it is `Subscript` that must be cleared.

```
Clear[Subscript]; D[Subscript[x, i][t], {t, 2}]
```

> Derivative[2][Subscript[x, i]][t]

which will be rendered as $\tt{x_i''[t]}$. Looks good now, but how many other subscripted variables have you cleared along with $\tt{x_i}$?

Comment: However, `D[Subscript[c, x]*x, x]` returns `Subscript[c, x] + x*Derivative[0, 1][Subscript][c, x]` instead of simply $c_x$, it being a coefficient, as `D` treats `Subscript` as a symbolic function. Any idea how to overcome this?