# Efficent ways to use NSolve, Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

hope you're having a nice day!

**Context**: I'm trying to constrain parameters from a model of [Orbital Resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance) equilibrium. In short, I know a parameter "$\Delta_{eq}$" which is derived from observations. I know a set of parameters {$m_1$,$m_2$,$M_*$,$q$,$f_1$,$f_{2p}$} and I know (not precisely yet) physical boundaries for variables $\alpha$, $hr_1$, $hr_2$, $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$, given $\Delta_{eq}$. Explicitly

$$\Delta_{eq}=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{m_1 m_2 \left(\alpha  m_2 (q+1)+m_1 q\right) \left(\text{hr}_1^4 q^2 \Sigma _2 f_{2 p}^2+\alpha ^{3/2} f_1^2 \text{hr}_2^4 (q+1)^2 \Sigma _1\right)}{\text{hr}_1^2 \text{hr}_2^2 M_*^2 q^2 (q+1)^2 \left(\text{hr}_1^2 m_2 \Sigma _2-\sqrt{\alpha } \text{hr}_2^2 m_1 \Sigma _1\right)}}$$

**My try**: Evaluating known values (observables) I can explore the parameters I'm interested in, first plotting the real part of

$$0.000492702 \sqrt{\frac{(0.000704487 \alpha +0.000933589) \left(5.6644 \alpha ^{3/2} \text{hr}_2^4 \Sigma _1+2.84934 \text{hr}_1^4 \Sigma _2\right)}{\text{hr}_1^2 \text{hr}_2^2 \left(0.000352244 \text{hr}_1^2 \Sigma _2-0.000933589 \sqrt{\alpha } \text{hr}_2^2 \Sigma _1\right)}}$$

and Manipulating

`Manipulate[Plot[Re[0.0004927023775077934* Sqrt[((0.0009335890199999999 + 0.00070448742*\[Alpha])* (5.6644*\[Alpha]^(3/2)*Subscript[hr, 2]^4*Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1] +  2.849344*Subscript[hr, 1]^4*Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2]))/ (Subscript[hr, 1]^2*Subscript[hr, 2]^2*(-0.0009335890199999999*Sqrt[\[Alpha]]* Subscript[hr, 2]^2*Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1] + 0.00035224371*Subscript[hr, 1]^2* Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2]))]], {\[Alpha], 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All],  {Subscript[hr, 1], 0.01, 0.05}, {Subscript[hr, 2], 0.01, 0.05},  {Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1], 10^(-6), 10^(-3)}, {Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2], 10^(-6), 10^(-3)}]`

What, at the time of this post, I've not been able to study is the constrained space of parameters that satisfy $\Delta_{eq} \approx 0.035$, of my particular interest. That is to say, solving:

`sol1 = Reduce[ Re[0.0004927023775077934*Sqrt[((0.00070448742*\[Alpha] + 0.0009335890199999999)* (5.6644*\[Alpha]^(3/2)*Subscript[hr, 2]^4*Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1] +  2.849344*Subscript[hr, 1]^4*Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2]))/(Subscript[hr, 1]^2* Subscript[hr, 2]^2*(0.00035224371*Subscript[hr, 1]^2* Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2] - 0.0009335890199999999*Sqrt[\[Alpha]]*Subscript[hr, 2]^2* Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1]))]] == 0.035 && 1/10^6 < Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2] <  Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1] < 1/10^3 && 0 < \[Alpha] < 1 && 0.009 < Subscript[hr, 1] <  0.1 && 0.009 < Subscript[hr, 2] < 0.1, {\[Alpha], Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 1],  Subscript[\[CapitalSigma], 2], Subscript[hr, 1], Subscript[hr, 2]}, Reals]`

**Question 1**: What can I do to efficently solve the problem? I've also tried with NSolve and constraining only $\Sigma$s.

**Question 2**: solving only for $\Sigma$s I've found that the solution is $\{\}$ empty for guessed $hr$s so, in the case that there's no solution for $\Delta_{eq}=0.035$, how can I find the minimum $\Delta_{eq}$? Also, is there any way to solve for $\Delta_{eq} \pm \delta\Delta$ given $\delta\{m_1,...,f_{2p}\}$ uncertainties?

*Disclaimer*: Tried to copy the code as Raw Input following [this question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) but couldn't do better. I apologize if the code is hard to read.

And by the way, I appreciate any suggestion/alternative regarding on the problem

Comment: Do you have multiple observations? If you have many you might determine the variables hr1, ... by optimization (e.g., =NonlinearModelFit)

Comment: @JackLaVigne This is not the case but it would be useful to consider it when possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to change the name of some of your variables, removing the subscripts. You can find many questions and answers that show that using variables with subscripts can create problems, [see this answer.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48174/whats-the-difference-between-variables-with-and-without-a-subscript)

Here is a function using your variables where I have, for example, substituted Subscript[hr, 1] with hr1, ...

```
fun[α_, hr1_, hr2_, Σ1_, Σ2_] := 
 0.0004927023775077934*
  Sqrt[((0.0009335890199999999 + 
        0.00070448742*α)*(5.6644*α^(3/2)*
         hr2^4*Σ1 + 
        2.849344*hr1^4*Σ2))/(hr1^2*
      hr2^2*(-0.0009335890199999999*Sqrt[α]*
         hr2^2*Σ1 + 
        0.00035224371*hr1^2*Σ2))]
```

Here is the Traditional form

```
TraditionalForm[fun[α, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to get variables in the ball park try this approach. Create a table iterating over the variables with the ranges from your `Manipulate`.

```
data = Table[
   {α, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2,
    fun[α, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2]},
   {α, 0, 0.5, 0.1},
   {hr1, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01},
   {hr2, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01},
   {Σ1, 10^-6, 10^-3, (10^-3 - 10^-6)/5},
   {Σ2, 10^-6, 10^-3, (10^-3 - 10^-6)/5}
   ];
```

`data` will have the dimensions

```
Dimensions@data
(* {6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6} *)
```

Flatten it

```
data = Flatten[data, 4];
```

This is a list of 5400 sub lists.

Select only those whose 6th element is Real

```
dataReal = Select[data, Im[#[[6]]] == 0 &];
```

This reduces it to 2929 sub lists.

Find the sub list whose absolute value is closest to 0.035.

```
minDataReal = Min[Map[(# - 0.035)^2 &, dataReal[[All, 6]]]]
(* 5.30542*10^-9 *)

Position[Map[(# - 0.035)^2 &, dataReal[[All, 6]]], minDataReal]
(* {{1236}} *)
```

This occurs at position 1236 in `dataReal`.

```
dataReal[[1236]]
(* {0.1, 0.04, 0.05, 251/1250000, 4001/5000000, 0.0349272} *)
```

Now plot it.

```
Module[
 {
  hr1 = 0.04,
  hr2 = 0.05,
  Σ1 = 251/1250000,
  Σ2 = 4001/5000000
  },
 Show[
  Plot[fun[α, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2],
   {α, 0, 0.5},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> Black
   ],
  Graphics[{
    Red,
    PointSize -> 0.025,
    Point[{0.1, 0.0349272}]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that hr2 hits an upper limit while the rest of the variables are within your bounds. This suggests that you might want to raise the upper limit of hr2.

You can fine tune the estimate by adjusting min, max and step of the variables.

If one sets `α` one is able to successfully run `FindInstance`.

```
FindInstance[
 {
  fun[0.1, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2] == 0.035,
  0.009 < hr1 < 0.1,
  0.009 < hr2 < 0.1,
  10^-6 < Σ1 < 10^-3,
  10^-6 < Σ2 < 10^-3
  },
 {hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2},
 Reals,
 5
 ]
(* {{hr1 -> 0.0754329, 
  hr2 -> 0.0478999, Σ1 -> 
   0.000213849, Σ2 -> 0.000247237}, {hr1 -> 0.0845794, 
  hr2 -> 0.0433808, Σ1 -> 
   0.0000638252, Σ2 -> 0.0000988564}, {hr1 -> 0.0845794,
   hr2 -> 0.0465941, Σ1 -> 
   0.000702261, Σ2 -> 0.000702261}, {hr1 -> 0.0775397, 
  hr2 -> 0.0673684, Σ1 -> 
   0.000731934, Σ2 -> 0.000731934}, {hr1 -> 0.0911567, 
  hr2 -> 0.0991313, Σ1 -> 
   0.000616756, Σ2 -> 0.000741676}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JackLaVigne Could you please give me a hint on why Reduce & NSolve didn't solve it? Also, do you think I could find a set of sublists with abs. values between Delta+- err easily? I'm not familiarized with Select, Map & Position.

Comment: You can get values that are within a particular error range via: `Select[dataReal, (#[[6]] - 0.035)^2 < 10^-6 &]`. Here I am using 10e-06 as the upper error value. You are supplying one equation with 6 unknowns and 4 two sided constraints. `NSolve` needs a determined system and `Reduce` runs without stopping on my system. It appears from the tabular data that you have the Sigma1 and Sigma2 constraints wired backwards.

Comment: `FindInstance` works if one sets `\[Alpha]`. You might want to try setting another variable while holding `\[Alpha]` constant.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jack's improved function `fun`, you could also try `NMinimize` to solve your problem and use the `"RandomSearch"` method and varying the seed to produce a large list of solution candidates. From here you can then study the histograms of individual variables from the good solutions. This should help you gauge what the solution space looks like, though note there will be bias in the sampling which might favour certain parts of the solution space :

```
fun[α_, hr1_, hr2_, Σ1_, Σ2_] := 
  0.0004927023775077934*
    Sqrt[((0.0009335890199999999 + 
                0.00070448742*α)*(5.6644*α^(3/2)*
                  hr2^4*Σ1 + 
                2.849344*hr1^4*Σ2))/(hr1^2*
            hr2^2*(-0.0009335890199999999*Sqrt[α]*
                  hr2^2*Σ1 + 
                0.00035224371*hr1^2*Σ2))]

target = 0.035;
solutionCandidates = Table[
   NMinimize[{Abs[(fun[α, hr1, hr2, Σ1, Σ2] - target)^2],
     0 < α < 0.5,
     0.01 < hr1 < 0.05,
     0.01 < hr2 < 0.05,
     10^-6 < Σ1 < 10^-3,
     10^-6 < Σ2 < 10^-3}, {α, hr1, 
     hr2, Σ1, Σ2}, 
    Method -> {"RandomSearch", "RandomSeed" -> i, 
      "SearchPoints" -> 10}]
   , {i, 30}];

(* select the best solutions with the lowest error *)
solutions = Select[solutionCandidates, #[[1]] < 10^-10 &][[All, 2]];

(* study the histogram of a particular parameter *)
Histogram[Σ2 /. solutions]
```